# Saving properties not supported by RealmSwift

Tags: ios, swift, realm

As per the **Realm Documentation, CGFloat** is not one of the types supported in Realm. So I have a Person Storage class as follows:-

```
class Person: Object {
@objc dynamic var height: Float = 0.0
@objc dynamic var weight: CGFloat = 5.0

override var description: String {
    return " { Height = \(height), Weight = \(weight)}"
 }
}
```

I know till the object of Person Class is added to realm, It will behave as normal swift object and will not be managed by Realm. **Once it is added to the realm, Realm will manage it.** So it will compile successfully.

Now I am adding the object to the realm, and then printing it.

```
let person = Person()
try! realm.write {
    realm.add(person)
}
print(realm.objects(Person.self).first)
```

> It is printing **Optional( { Height = 0.0, Weight = 5.0})**

As per my understanding, **since type CGFloat is not supported by Realm, it should crash at runtime when I am adding object to Realm.**

> So what is going under the hoods here? Also which Type is being used to save CGFloat value?

Comment: ```/// The native type used to store the CGFloat, which is Float on
   32-bit architectures and Double on 64-bit architectures.```

Comment: “CGFloat properties are discouraged, as the type is not platform independent.” , that’s from the doc. Discouraged does not mean it’s not supported. You can probably find out more details by doing some research

Comment: Makes Sense. Thanks...

Comment: Why do you need to manage a CGFloat? You could also use getters and setters to handle the Float->CGFloat if you class must only expose a CGFloat.

Comment: @Jay Its not about having custom properties....Its about how Realm is working

Comment: There are a couple of things. First is the comment from @JoakimDanielson above. CGFloat properties are supported but discouraged. A CGFloat is platform specific so I was asking why do you need a CGFloat as there may be other options that are better supported. Second thing is if you want to know a property type, you can create the object in Realm and then open the file with Realm Studio and you can see the property type; in this case the GGFloat is stored as a double 'under the hood'. Realm is working correctly and as advertised; was there more to the question or has it been answered?