# How to save CGFloat and Color to realm DB?

Tags: swift, realm, data-persistence

I want to use realm to save data but as far as I understand realm does not support `CGFloat` and `Color` property, I searched for solution but it seems there is no answer.

[Saving properties not supported by RealmSwift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56392378/saving-properties-not-supported-by-realmswift)

In documentation said : **“CGFloat properties are discouraged, as the type is not platform independent.”**

In my app I use DragGesture and the value that returns for `width` and `height` are CGFloat this is my struct:

```
struct Card : Identifiable {
  
  var id = UUID()
  var name : String
  var color : Color
  var y : CGFloat = 0
  var x : CGFloat = 0
  
}
```

and DB so far :

```
class cardDB : Object {
  
  @objc dynamic var id = UUID()
  @objc dynamic var name = ""
  
}
```

Is there any way to save these two property to realm DB?

Comment: There are many other ways to represent these things. For the `CGFloat`, you can use a `Float` or `Double` instead. For the `Color`, you can store a hex string, 3 or 4 integers representing RGB(A), or a string representing the name of a color that your app would recognise. Choose the best representation that suits your specific situation, which you haven't described.

Comment: As you said I used Float instead of CGFloat and it works could you explain more about Color?

Comment: The structure in your question has a property `var color : Color` so he was stating we don't know what that `Color` type is. Perhaps a UIColor?

Answer (score 1):

Map `CGFloat` to `Float`.

I’m not sure what your `Color` type is. Assuming it’s like `UIColor`, and is in RGBA format, you should be able to create a struct containing `Float` values for red, green, blue, and alpha and save those.

### Edit:

Your `Card` struct contains the following property:

```
var color : Color
```

That declares a variable `color` of type `Color`. `Color` Is not a system type. It might as well read

```
var color : CatFood
```

We have no idea what type `Color` type is. Based on the name, we can guess that it contains a description of a color, but that’s a guess.

You should command-click on the type `Color` in your project and select “jump to definition”. Then see what that type is. If it is an alias of UIColor or CGColor, great. If it is some custom type, add that definition to the bottom of your question.

Comment: I changed the CGFloat to Float it works what do you mean Color type? I don't get it  could you explain more about Color

Comment: @fdvfarzin The structure in your question as a property `var color : Color` so he was stating we don't know what that `Color` type is. Perhaps a UIColor?